# linux で 特定のフォルダに対し、その名前を変更不能とし、かつフォルダ内にファイル生成可能とする方法

Tags: linux

linux で 特定のフォルダに対し、その名前を変更不能とし、
かつフォルダ内にファイル生成可能とする方法を探しています。

用途は以下のイメージです。

- 特定の実験データを保持するフォルダで、そのフォルダ名は実験と紐付いているため変えてほしくない。
- 実験データはボリュームが大きいためコピーは容易ではなく、そのフォルダ内で作業をしたい。
- フォルダ内で作業した成果物を同一のフォルダに作成したい。その理由はそのフォルダ内に存在する実験結果のファイルと相対パス的な関係性があるため。

フォルダの権限をw-xにしないとファイル作成できないですが、w-xだとフォルダ名が変えられてしまう・・・
どなたか教えてください。

Comment: フォルダ名を変えたい人は、なんでフォルダ名を変えたいんですかね？

Comment: 特定のフォルダ(例えば`/data`)自体の名前変更を不能としたいのか、`/data`以下に作成するファイル/フォルダ名の名前変更を不能としたいのか、どちらでしょうか? 後者の場合、作成者は名前変更してもよいのでしょうか?

Comment: まぁ、お使いのファイルシステムが ext3 か ext4 であれば `sudo chattr +a target_dir` とすればできなくはありません。ディレクトリのリネームはできなくなるのですが、ディレクトリ内に作成されたファイルのリネーム・削除ができなくなります(ファイル内容の変更は可能です)。

Comment: @豚吐露 フォルダ名を変えたいというか、誤って変えてしまうことを避けたいということです。

Comment: @ user20098 /data自体の名前変更も不能としたいし、data以下に作成するファイル・フォルダの名前変更も不能としたいです。ただし、ファイルの新規追加は可能としたいです

Comment: @metropolis なるほど。拡張属性を使うのですね。参考になります。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ディレクトリに対して**スティッキービット**を立てる方法があります。

```
$ chmod o+t dir
```

参考：
[スティッキービット（Sticky Bit） - 特殊なアクセス権](https://kazmax.zpp.jp/linux_beginner/stickybit.html)

> スティッキービット（Sticky Bit）が設定されたディレクトリでは、すべてのユーザーがファイル・ディレクトリを書き込めますが、所有者だけ（rootは除く）しか削除できなくなります。
>   /tmp ディレクトリは、スティッキービット（Sticky Bit）が設定されています。

Comment: スティッキービットって聞いたことあったけど、こういうときに役立つんですね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: @kiitosu 既にご承知かもしれませんが、`dir` の親ディレクトリのオーナー・パーミッションの設定次第では `dir` 自体をリネームすることが可能になってしまいます。データ処理を行うのは一般ユーザだけ、ということであれば親ディレクトリのオーナーを root にして パーミッションを 0755 などに設定する対処も必要かと思われます。